# AngularJS redirect route based on Service

Tags: angularjs

is there a way to redirect a route based on a condition comming from a service?
Currently I tried to do it like that:

```
.otherwise({
resolve: {
            redirect: function ($routeParams, $location, $http, $cookies) {
                $http({method: 'GET', url: '/user/' + $cookies.id}).success(function(data) {
                    if(data.isSuperUser || data.isStaff) {
                        $location.path('/info/info');
                    } else {
                        $location.path('/unity/list');
                    }
                }).error(function() {
                    $location.path('/unity/list');
                });
            }
        }});
```

But it always fails with Provider not found. How could I do that correctly?

Comment: Are you getting Unknown provider error ?

Comment: yes, it seems that $location is the problem and it only gives the error when i concat/minify the javascript with yeoman. On the development version it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's erroring on minify it's probably because it's renaming things on you. Dependency injection usually gets crushed on minification. Try changing your redirect to this:

```
redirect: ["$routeParams", "$location", "$http", "$cookies", function ($routeParams, $location, $http, $cookies) {
    ...
}]
```

Here's there documentation on it: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 look for "A Note on Minification"